# PHPExcel borders being overridden?

Tags: php, border, phpexcel, cells

I have a class that creates a PHPExcel document. Below are the styles I use. Hopefully they are fairly obvious from their names.

```php
private $default_style = array(
    'font' => array(
        'name' => 'Verdana',
        'color' => array('rgb' => '000000'),
        'size' => 11
    ),
    'alignment' => array(
        'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER
    ),
    'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'AAAAAA')
        )
    )
);

private $title_style = array(
    'font' => array(
        'bold' => true
    ),
    'fill' => array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array('rgb' => '5CACEE')
    ),
    'alignment' => array(
        'wrap' => true
    ),
    'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'AAAAAA')
        )
    )
);


private $new_swap_style = array(
    'font' => array(
        'bold' => true
    ),
    'fill' => array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array('rgb' => 'F9690E')
    ),
    'alignment' => array(
        'wrap' => true
    ),
    'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'AAAAAA')
        )
    )
);

private $odd_row_style = array(
    'fill' => array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array('rgb' => 'CCCCCC')
    ),
    'borders' => array(
        'allborders' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('rgb' => 'AAAAAA')
        )
    )
);

private $outline_border = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'outline' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '676767')
        )
    )
);

private $right_border = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'right' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('rgb' => '676767')
        )
    )
);
```

I apply the `odd_row_style` using this piece of code:

```php
if ($key % 2 != 0) {
    $as->getStyle('A'.$row.':'.$last_col.$row)
       ->applyFromArray($this->odd_row_style);
}
```

Other than that, the only other styles I apply are the `outline_border` and `right_border` styles. They are applied at the end of the data I loop through like so:

```php
// $row equals the last row after the data is looped through
$as->getStyle('D3:H'.($row))->applyFromArray($this->outline_border);
$as->getStyle('E3:E'.($row))->applyFromArray($this->right_border);
```

For some reason, the border in the `default_style` is getting overridden, but is applied again when I add the `outline_border` and `right_border` styles.

It is more obviously seen in the screenshot on rows 10 and 11. You can see that there is no border between them, so the gray rows mesh together. However, the border is applied properly under the "New" title in the same rows.

[image]

I tried adding the `default_style` again right before adding the `outline_border` and `right_border` styles with no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help!

## UPDATE

I've realized that when I set the `odd_row_style` to a row, filling the cell colors overrides the borders, even though I have re-included the border default. It seems to do this whether or not the cell has a value. See cells F10:G11 (values), and A10:C11 (no values) in the picture above.

Even weirder, when I applied `default_style` to the whole sheet, the border colors were `#c1c1c1` for everything, instead of `#aaaaaa` like I tried to set them.

This is driving me insane, if anyone can please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, setting the border style using the `->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray()` methods threw everything out of wack for me. If I set the cells explicitly using `->getStyle()->applyFromArray()` by entering one or more cells, it works as expected. I'm not sure if this is the expected result or a bug, but I opened an issue on their github. Feel free to track it [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/634).